# having trouble writing a query that list all salesmen that did not sell to a particular customer

Tags: mysql, sql

I was successful in writing the query that lists salesmen that did sell to a particular customer, but not those that have not. I suspect it is because the same salesmen that sold to the specific customer, also sold to other customers.

```
  select a.name from salesperson a inner join orders b on 
  a.salesperson_id = b.salesperson_id where cust_id="4";
```

I was thinking that modifying the same query like this would do the trick:

```
  .... a.salesperson_id <> b.salesperson_id where cust_id="4";
```

But the result lists all the salesmen. This is most likely due to the  fact that the same salesmen that were returned in the original query, also sold to other customers

The 3 tables look like this:

```
               Salesperson table

                     salesperson_ID,     Name,     Age,      Salary

                         1                   Abe        61       140000
                         2                   Bob        34        44000
                         5                  Chris       34        40000
                         7                   Dan        41        52000
                         8                   Ken        57       115000
                         11                  Joe        38        38000


                   Customer table

                   cust_ID,       Name,     City           Industry Type

                      4            faralon    sacramento            H
                      6             Apple       cupertino           S
                      7            Honda       NY                   B
                      9            Kolb      Oshkosh                B




          Orders table

             Number,        Order_date,   cust_id,  salesperson_id,   Amount

            10              8/2/1996           4             2         540
             20             1/30/1999          4             8        1800
             30             7/14/1995          9             1         460
            40             1/29/1998           7             2        2400
            50             2/3/1998            6              7        600
            60             3/2/1998            6              7        720
            70             5/6/1998            9              7        150
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. ~Alpinehyker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select a.name from salesperson a 
left join orders b on a.salesperson_id = b.salesperson_id and b.cust_id="4"
where b.Number is null
```

So, get all salepersons, [`left join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) to orders for customer `4`, and return only rows where there is no such order.

I am assuming that `Number` is the primary key for `Orders`, or at least `not null`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM `Salesperson` AS s
LEFT JOIN `Orders` AS o ON o.`salesperson_id` = s.`salesperson_ID`
WHERE
    o.`cust_id` NOT IN (4)
GROUP BY s.`salesperson_ID`;
```

Answer to your 2nd question:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*) AS num_of_orders
     ,s.`Name`
FROM `Salesperson` AS s
LEFT JOIN `Orders` AS o ON o.`salesperson_id` = s.`salesperson_ID`
GROUP BY s.`salesperson_ID`
HAVING num_of_orders >= 2;
```

...and 3rd question. (assuming you have your `highAchiever` table ready)

```
INSERT INTO `highAchiever`
(`Name`,`Age`)
SELECT 
    `Name`
    ,`Age`
FROM `Salesperson`
WHERE
    `Salary` >= 100000;
```

Comment: I don't think so - that will give you the salespersons for all orders which aren't for customer 4 - it will only exclude salespersons who have only made sales to customer 4 (or no sales at all). Also, you'll get duplicate rows: one for each order, not one for each salesperson.

Comment: This worked! thank you. I have a couple more queries that I am having difficulty with. perhaps you could help on these as well? question 2...   2. The name of salespeople that have 2 or more orders


3. Write a SQL statement to insert rows into a table called highAchiever(Name, Age), where a salesperson must have a salary of 100,000 or greater to be included in the table.  thanks much.

Comment: @marcin Thank you so much for your assistance! The syntax of the query for the second question that I was attempting was close to what you provided, but I just couldn't get it right. As for the third question... I was completely over-thinking it. Thank you, I am grateful for your assistance and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

All salespeople who have NOT sold to customer_ID 4:

```
SELECT s.Name FROM Salesperson AS s
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
ON s.salesperson_ID = o.salesperson_ID
WHERE o.customer_ID <> 4
GROUP BY o.salesperson_ID;
```